# PHP pdo query insert twice sometime

Tags: php, database, pdo, duplicates

I have a android app which submit data through php but sometime the data insert twice when I submit the data.
I'm sure the issue is not on the app as the button is disabled once I press the button. Please help me spot my mistake. Thanks!
Following is the data inserted:
[image]

Following is my query:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $area = $_POST['area'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $batch = $_POST['batch'];
    $workerName = $_POST['workerName'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $tank = $_POST['tank'];
    $sid= '';
    $submissionDateTime = $_POST['submissionDateTime'];
    
    
    require_once 'connectdb.php';
    
    $stmt = $conn ->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT sid FROM feedingforms WHERE area = :area AND tank = :tank AND date = :date AND batch = :batch AND time = :time");
    $stmt->bindParam(":area", $_POST['area']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":tank", $_POST['tank']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":date", $_POST['date']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":batch", $_POST['batch']);
    $stmt->bindParam(":time", $_POST['time']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();//fecth
    switch ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        case "0":
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO feedingforms(sid, area, date, batch, workerName, submissionDateTime, remarks, time, tank) VALUES(:sid, :area, :date,:batch,:workerName,:submissionDateTime, :remarks, :time,:tank)");
        $stmt2->bindValue(":sid", $sid);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":area", $area);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":date", $date);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":batch", $batch);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":workerName", $workerName);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":submissionDateTime", $submissionDateTime);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":remarks", $remarks);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":time", $time);
        $stmt2->bindValue(":tank", $tank);
    
        if ($stmt2->execute()) {
            $result["success"]= "1";
            $result["message"] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            $conn = null;
            exit;
            break;
    
        }else{
            $result["success"]= "0";
            $result["message"] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);
            $conn = null;
            exit;
            break;
        }
        default:
        $result["success"]= "2";
        $result["message"] = "duplicate";
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
        $conn = null;
    
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're using `switch` in a very strange way. Looks like a plain old `if..else` would be a much better fit, eg `if ($stmt->fetch()) { /* do insert */ } else { /* add duplicate message */ }`

Comment: I was using if else initially same issue.

Comment: There's nothing in the code above that would execute the same `INSERT` statement more than once for the same request. Your logic for detecting duplicates seems backwards though